# Kivy and Python threading - how get data between them

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I've some problems with python(threading) and kivy:

Here is some code:

```
import kivy
import threading 
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        self.counter = 0        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "Thread is running "+str(self.counter)
            app.button.text = self.set_button(self.counter)
            app.button.text = str(self.counter)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    def count(self):
        self.counter += 1
        app.button.text = str(self.counter)     
    def set_button(self, value):
        app.button.text = str(value)

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__ (self, thread_object):
        App.__init__(self) 
        self.thread_object = thread_object      
    def callback(self,instance):
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)
        self.thread_object.count()
    def build(self):
        self.button = Button(text='Hello World')
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        return self.button

thread = Thread()
thread.start()
app = MyApp(thread)
app.run()
```

Now - this code opens a kivy app with one button. The task is: pressing the button some data should appear in the threaded code (it does by the "count" method.

Problem is the reverse way - the threaded code should change the text of the button. I've tried two ways:

- Write it directly: `app.button.text = str(self.counter)`
- Write it via a method "set_button": `app.button.text = self.set_button(self.counter)`

Both of them show up an error "Attribute Error: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'button'".

Is there any way to exchange data directly without requesting, even without doing that pointer stuff here with "thread_object"

```
def __init__ (self, thread_object):
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey! It's unclear. I have 3 questions: you asked->  **Is there any way to exchange data directly without requesting?**, 1st question is: Do you want to use threads or not?   You asked-> **shows up an error "Attribute Error: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'button'"** 2nd question is :, An application can be built if you return a widget on build() method, So you why don't you create a new class that inherits a widget, 3rd is: why don't you use kivy language and give an id to the button?

Comment: Hi, 1st: I want use threading for calculating things and a second one to send these data via sockets or the serial port. 2nd: I'm new at kivy and this code i posted is like the hello world example from the kivywebpage. 3rd: I tried to use kv language 2 years ago in another project and the problem was to build the gui dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will probably solve all your problems. That's the way I like to code while dealing with threads and with kivy language.

Here is **thread.py** file

```
import threading   
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Thread(BoxLayout):
    counter = NumericProperty(0)

    def Counter_function(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.lbl.text = "{}".format(self.counter)

    def First_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(target = self.Counter_function).start()
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.lbl.text = "{}".format(self.counter)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('thread.kv')
        return Thread() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is **thread.kv** file

```
<Thread>:
    Button:
        text: "use thread"
        on_release: root.First_thread()
    Button:
        text: "Hit me"
        on_release: root.Counter_function()
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: "Numbers"
```

Now, You said in your comment that you struggle with dynamically loading the GUI. So, here's an example. 
**threading.py**

```
import threading   
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
[SideBar@BoxLayout]:
    content: content
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: .2,1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # just add a id that can be accessed later on
        id: content

<Root>:
    Button:
        center_x: root.center_x
        text: 'press to add_widgets'
        size_hint: .2, .2
        on_press:
            sb.content.clear_widgets()
            root.load_content(sb.content)
    SideBar:
        id: sb
''')

class Root(BoxLayout):

    def load_content(self, content):
        for but in range(20):
            content.add_widget(Button(text=str(but)))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: The `Counter_function` doesn't seem to end when the main application quits.